# Calculating all possible sub-sequences of a given length (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm

If I have a sequence as follows (let's say it's an `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

Then what's the cleanest way to compute all possible (continuous and non-continuous) [subsequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of a given length? Ordering of the results in the result set isn't important, but it shouldn't include duplicates.

e.g. If I want to compute all possible subsequences of length 3 the result set would be:

```
[A, B, C]
[A, B, D]
[A, B, E]
[A, C, D]
[A, C, E]
[A, D, E]
[B, C, D]
[B, C, E]
[B, D, E]
[C, D, E]
```

---

For the record, the accepted answer below gave me a good starting point, and here's the code I've gone with that is updated to use some of the new .NET 3.5 extension methods:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsequences<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    int count)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
    else
    {
        var skip = 1;
        foreach (var first in source)
        {
            foreach (var rest in source.Skip(skip).Subsequences(count - 1))
            {
                yield return Enumerable.Repeat(first, 1).Concat(rest);
            }

            skip++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having IEnumerable<T> is detrimental to you, because you will going over the list multiple times, so having indexer access would be a huge boon for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had success with IanG's [`PermuteUtils`](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/16/permuterate) class:

```
char[] items = new char[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

foreach (IEnumerable<char> permutation in PermuteUtils.Permute(items, 3)) {
    Console.Write("[");
    foreach (char c in permutation) {
        Console.Write(" " + c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(" ]");
}
```

Results in:

```
[ A B C ]
[ A B D ]
[ A B E ]
[ A C B ]
[ A C D ]
[ A C E ]
[ A D B ]
[ A D C ]
[ A D E ]
[ A E B ]
[ A E C ]
[ A E D ]
[ B A C ]
[ B A D ]
[ B A E ]
[ B C A ]
[ B C D ]
[ B C E ]
[ B D A ]
[ B D C ]
...
```

Comment: That isn't quite what I'm after; that is all possible permutations but, for example [A, D, B] is not a subsequence because it isn't in the same order.

Comment: Then again, it's easy to modify to give the right result so I'll give you the accepted answer. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] data = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    WalkSubSequences(data, 3);
}

public static void WalkSubSequences<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, int sequenceLength)
{
    T[] selected = new T[sequenceLength];
    WalkSubSequences(data.ToArray(), selected, 0, sequenceLength);
}
private static void WalkSubSequences<T>(T[] data, T[] selected,
    int startIndex, int sequenceLength)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i + sequenceLength <= data.Length; i++)
    {
        selected[selected.Length - sequenceLength] = data[i];
        if (sequenceLength == 1)
        {
            ShowResult(selected);
        }
        else
        {
            WalkSubSequences(data, selected, i + 1, sequenceLength - 1);
        }
    }
}

private static void ShowResult<T>(T[] selected)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(selected[0]);
    for (int j = 1; j < selected.Length; j++)
    {
        sb.Append(';').Append(selected[j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a recursive algorithm for this. I'm sorry, but it has been a while since I did anything in C#, so I'll just give pseudo-code here.

```
function allPossible(iterator, length, currSubSeq, allResults) {
    // Add the current sub sequence to the results if it is the correct length.
    if (currSubSeq.length == length) {
        copy = currSubSeq.copy();
        allResults.add(copy);
    }
    // If it is too long, return early.
    else if (currSubSeq.length > length) {
        return allResults;
    }

    // Get the next item from the iterator and handle both cases:
    // I.E. when it is, and when it isn't in a sub sequence.
    item = iterator.getNext();
    allPossible(iterator, currSubSeq, allResults);
    currSubSeq.add(item);
    allPossible(iterator, currSubSeq, allResults);

    return allResults;
}
```

Then you find all possible sub sequences by calling `allPossible` with an `iterator` that produces all elements in your original sequence, the `length` that you want your sub-sequences, an empty sequence of items for `currSubSeq`, and an empty sequence of item sequences for `allResults`. I'm assuming pass-by-reference semantics for all the parameters. Sorry that I couldn't give you the proper C# implementation, but I'm sure you know more than enough to take my algorithm sketch and turn it into code.

One last thing. Because this algorithm is recursive, you may have a stack overflow if you run it on a very long sequence with a large `length` parameter since stack usage is O(2^N) where N = `length`. I don't think this is a big problem because the algorithm has O(2^N) run-time because of the nature of the problem, so you shouldn't try to run it with a large enough `length` to overflow the stack anyway!

**CAVEAT** I haven't actually tested this pseudo-code, so there may be something subtle I haven't thought of.

Comment: @A. Levy: "A "non-continuous sub-sequence" isn't a sub-sequence."  He's using the proper mathematical definition of subsequence, which is exactly as he described.

Comment: The question uses 'subsequence' correctly. And subsets are unordered, so that's an entirely wrong word to use too.

Comment: @Kevin and @ShreevatsaR: Thanks you both for correcting my misunderstanding of subsequences. I was thinking "substring" apparently. I've removed that bit of ignorant pedantry from my answer. @Greg Beech, if you read this comment, perhaps you can include a link to a definition of subsequences so ignoramuses like me can be educated. Such as: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution storing the state in a array of bools. It works by creating the following states on each `Next()` call (n = 5, k = 3).

```
1 1 1 . .  Move last 1 right once.
1 1 . 1 .  Move last 1 right once.
1 1 . . 1  Move last 1 right once.
1 . 1 1 .  Move the second last 1 right once and all 1s from the right back.
1 . 1 . 1  Move last 1 right once.
1 . . 1 1  Move the second last 1 right once (and all 1s from the right back.)
. 1 1 1 .  Move the third last 1 right once and all 1s from the right back.
. 1 1 . 1  Move last 1 right once.
. 1 . 1 1  Move the second last 1 right once (and all 1s from the right back.)
. . 1 1 1  Move the third last 1 right once (and all 1s from the right back.)
```

This state can then be used to select the coresponding items from the supplied sequence for every state.

At first the initialization.

```
public static Boolean[] Initialize(Int32 n, Int32 k)
{
    return Enumerable.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(true, k),
                             Enumerable.Repeat(false, n - k)).ToArray();
}
```

The code to move to the next combination (subsequence).

```
public static Boolean Next(this Boolean[] list)
{
    Int32 lastOneIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(list, true);

    if (lastOneIndex == -1)
    {
        return false; // All zeros. 0000000
    }
    else if (lastOneIndex < list.Length - 1)
    {
        // Move the last one right once. 1100X00 => 11000X0
        list.MoveBlock(lastOneIndex, lastOneIndex, lastOneIndex + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Int32 lastZeroIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(list, false, lastOneIndex);

        if (lastZeroIndex == -1)
        {
            return false; // All ones. 1111111
        }
        else
        {
            Int32 blockEndIndex = Array.LastIndexOf(list, true, lastZeroIndex);

            if (blockEndIndex == -1)
            {
                // Move all ones back to the very left. 0000XXX => XXX0000
                list.MoveBlock(lastZeroIndex + 1, lastOneIndex, 0);

                return false; // Back at initial position.
            }
            else
            {
                // Move the block end right once. 11X0011 => 110X011
                list.MoveBlock(blockEndIndex, blockEndIndex, blockEndIndex + 1);
                // Move the block of ones from the very right back left. 11010XX => 1101XX0
                list.MoveBlock(lastZeroIndex + 1, lastOneIndex, blockEndIndex + 2);
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Finally some helper methods.

```
public static void MoveBlock(this Boolean[] list, Int32 oldStart, Int32 oldEnd, Int32 newStart)
{
    list.ClearBlock(oldStart, oldEnd);
    list.SetBlock(newStart, newStart + oldEnd - oldStart);
}

public static void SetBlock(this Boolean[] list, Int32 start, Int32 end)
{
    list.SetBlockToValue(start, end, true);
}

public static void ClearBlock(this Boolean[] list, Int32 start, Int32 end)
{
    list.SetBlockToValue(start, end, false);
}

public static void SetBlockToValue(this Boolean[] list, Int32 start, Int32 end, Boolean value)
{
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        list[i] = value;
    }
}
```

And a usage example using a string instead of a list.

```
var sequence = "ABCDE";

var state = Initialize(sequence.Count(), 5);

do
{
    Console.WriteLine(new String(sequence.Where((_, idx) => state[idx]).ToArray()));
}
while (state.Next());
```