# Create all possible buffers of a max length in C#

Tags: c#, .net

For our embedded device we defined a communication protocol with RS232 (COM port).

Now I'd like to do some exploiting/vulnerability tests that sends all possible buffers of a maximum length.

So I need some code that creates a list of all possible byte pattern for a given length.

For example for a given length 2 i want this list:

```
0x00
0x01
...
0xFF
0x0000
0x0001
...
0xFFFF
```

Any suggestion how to create this list in C#?

Thx

Comment: A `for` cycle from `0` to `0xFFFF` with a `ushort` variable?

Comment: Your sample output is more confusing than helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating all possible sub-sequences of a given length (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852536/calculating-all-possible-sub-sequences-of-a-given-length-c)

Comment: @Adriano: But then for example I don't get 0x00 and 0x0000 in the output.

Comment: @weston: The question in your link is about permutation. I'm not sure if I can use it too. I'll look at it in more detail.

Comment: Do you have to output that as a string then send via RS232? Sure? In that case (sounds odd, anyway) just **format it** as hexadecimal  (String.Format or ToString(), depends what you're using. MSDN for details).

Comment: No sory for the missunderstanding. I don't want to send it as a string. I want to send all bossible byte-patterns of length 1 to length n.

Comment: @woodtluk then (see [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20953884/1207195)) you don't need anything more complicated than a single for loop (whatever packet size is).

Answer (score 2):

Base code is always the same: a for loop. To send all possible values you have to simply cycle them.

```
for (int i=0; i < numberOfBytes; ++i) 
{
    for (BigInteger j=0; j < BigInteger.Pow(2, i * 8); ++j) 
    {
        SendData(j.ToByteArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: From reading the question it seems that the OP wants all things of length two, length three, length four, and so on up to a maximum length so I think you want two loops, one to vary numberOfBytes and one to then count the possibilities. Then of course making sure your byte array is padded to the appropriate length.

Comment: @Chris it's what he'll get (of course SendData() shouldn't _trim_ leading zeros). He may need to change second function (I'll update).

Comment: In your first example you only send the range 0x0000 to 0xFFFE. You need one last call to `SendData(0xFFFF)` outside the loop or use a larger data type and include the max value `for (int i=0; i <= 65535; ++i)` as your loop (However, good catch on not doing `<=` when comparing to `MaxValue`, lots of people mess that up.)

Comment: @Adriano: Either that is doing some magic or I'm not being clear. I think it needs to return `0x01` and `0x0001` as two separate things. As I see it both of these correspond to the same value of i (give or take endianness which always confuses me) so your code will only return one of them.

Comment: @Chris you're d*** right! I completely misundertsood his question! In this case it's even more simple, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
private static void SequencesInner(byte[] bytes, int i, Action<byte[]> action)
{
    if (i == bytes.Length)
    {
        action(bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        for (int v = 0; v < 256; v++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(v);
            SequencesInner(bytes, j, action);
        }
    }
}

private static void Sequences(int length, Action<byte[]> action)
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= length; n++)
    {
        SequencesInner(new byte[n], 0, action);
    }
}
```

---

### Complete Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void SequencesInner(byte[] bytes, int i, Action<byte[]> action)
        {
            if (i == bytes.Length)
            {
                action(bytes);
            }
            else
            {
                int j = i + 1;
                for (int v = 0; v < 256; v++)
                {
                    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(v);
                    SequencesInner(bytes, j, action);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Sequences(int length, Action<byte[]> action)
        {
            for (int n = 1; n <= length; n++)
            {
                SequencesInner(new byte[n], 0, action);
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var maxBufferSize = 2;
            var outputFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
            {
                Sequences(
                    maxBufferSize,
                    a => sw.WriteLine(sb.Clear().Append("0x").Append(String.Join("", Array.ConvertAll(a, x => x.ToString("X2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))))));
                sw.Flush();
            }
            var process = Process.Start("notepad.exe", outputFilePath);
            process.WaitForExit();
            File.Delete(outputFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Action` is not a good function name due to it already existing in the .net framework (you even use it in your code).

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken but the current question seems to ask for *all possible byte sequences of length up to N*, which will take a long time to send assuming:

- 115200 baud rate
- 10 bits per byte
- Number of possible byte sequences of length N = 256^N
- My math is right...

The number of possible sequences of length 1 to 4 is 4311810304 with a total byte count of 17230332160, which is 17 days to send.

So the best algorithm may be (n.b. will need to send buffers direct rather than store them I imagine):

```
public static List<byte[]> GetBuffers(int maxLength)
{
    if (maxLength > 4) throw new InvalidOperationException("Fail");
    var result = new List<byte[]>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++)
    {
        var max = 1 << (i * 8);
        for (long j = 0; j < max; j++)
        {
            // Can remove the Reverse() if endianness/ordering doesn't matter
            var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(j).Take(i).Reverse().ToArray());
            result.Add(buffer);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you still want to run the test and you want longer sequences, you can modify this to use BigInteger.ToByteArray as per @Adriano's answer.

Comment: Your bytes are bigger than usual for a start. Most people just have 8 bits in their bytes... The rest sounds plausible though but such is the price for thorough security checking...

Comment: Sorry, its an RS232 thing, 10 bits = 8 data bits + stop bit + parity [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Speed)

Comment: Ah, Cool. I did think it was strange that somebody talking about baud rates and so on would be wrong about that. I'll file that away for future reference. :)

Answer (score -1):

As weston pointed out, this is basically a permutation problem.

So you can use the post he linked to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852536/calculating-all-possible-sub-sequences-of-a-given-length-c but the code he linked to will not re-use used letters, so you won't get the full list of permutations like you want.  This can be fixed by modifying the excellent code linked to in that post (found here - http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/09/16/permuterate) to be this instead

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PermuteUtils
{
    // Returns an enumeration of enumerators, one for each permutation
    // of the input.
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int count)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            yield return new T[0];
        }
        else
        {
            int startingElementIndex = 0;
            foreach (T startingElement in list)
            {
                IEnumerable<T> remainingItems = list;// - Removed to get all permutations AllExcept(list, startingElementIndex);

                foreach (IEnumerable<T> permutationOfRemainder in Permute(remainingItems, count - 1))
                {
                    yield return Concat<T>(
                        new T[] { startingElement },
                        permutationOfRemainder);
                }
                startingElementIndex += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // Enumerates over contents of both lists.
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
    {
        foreach (T item in a) { yield return item; }
        foreach (T item in b) { yield return item; }
    }

}
```

Then to do what you want, we just need to get the permutations of a list of 2, 3 and 4 for all the hex digits

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] items = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};

```
    for (int length = 2; length <= 4; length++)
    {
        foreach (IEnumerable<char> permutation in PermuteUtils.Permute(items, length))
        {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("0x");
            foreach (char c in permutation)
            {
                output.Append(c);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And all the permutations are printed out for you.  You can then covert it to any format you need (or build the format you need instead of just a string).