# Calculate the total amount (number) of combinations of a set with the specified combination length?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, math, combinations

Having a set of elements, which in this case is an Array of 3 characters/elements {A, B, C}:

```
char[] charSet = "ABC".ToCharArray();
```

I would like to write a generic usage function to help determine which would be the total amount of combinations that can be generated OF THE SPECIFIED LENGTH and determining too the amount of possible combinations with and without repetition. To avoid possible mistakes: this question is not about combo/perm generation, just calculation.

A simple uncompleted example to understand me:

```
public static long CalculateCombinations(int setLength, int comboLength, bool allowRepetition)
{
    return result;
}
```

( where `setLength` is the amount of elements in the set, `comboLength` is the desired length of each combination, and `allowRepetition` a deterministic flag to help calculate the amount of combinations when and when not elements repetition is allowed in each combination. )

Then, if I have the same character set specified above, and I want to calculate the amount of possible combinations with repetition, the algorithm should return a value of 9, which would be the equivalent amount to this serie of combinations:

```
1: AA
2: AB
3: AC
4: BA
5: BB
6: BC
7: CA
8: CB
9: CC
```

The same algorithm should return me a value of 6 if I dont want repetition, which would be the equivalent amount to this serie of combinations:

```
1: AB
2: AC
3: BA
4: BC
5: CA
6: CB
```

Basically I'm trying to reproduce what this online service can do: http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/combination-permutation-tools/combination-generator/ however I tried to investigate and implement different 'nCr' formulas around the WWW (like http://www.vcskicks.com/code-snippet/combination.php ) and **StackOverflow** threads (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26312275/1248295 ), but i don't get it how to calculate it when the combination length factor and repetition is involved in the calculation. Maybe this could be too basic than what it appears to me, but maths are not my forte.

My question: how can I write an algorithm that can calculate what I explained?. Would be very grateful if someone could link a formula and its implementation in C# or VB.NET.

Comment: As @Lazar Ljubenović mentioned in his answer, these are called permutations. A great example of the non-repetitive version can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/852542/3602352).

Comment: @Aly El-Haddad Thanks for comment but as I clarified in my question: 'this question is not about combination/permutation generation, its just about  calculation.' (that is, a function that calculates the amount of combinations to generate. A implementation of the required formula to do so.)

Comment: Now I can't share the solution answering my own question because one "moderator" decided to mark my question as a (false positive) duplicate. Great for the StackOverflow free moderation cocnept... where everyone with no justified reason can harass others or for a misinterpretation or just for NOT READING THE QUESTION can cause other problems to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try it with three characters, `A`, `B` and `C` (`n = 3`) and combo length of `k = 2`, as your example states.

## With repetition

- We start with two empty spaces.
- The first empty space can be filled in 3 possible ways.
- For each of three possible ways, the second space can be filled in another three possible ways.

This gives you a total of `3 × 3` possibilities.

In general, there are `n ^ k` possibilities.

## Without repetition

- We start with two empty spaces.
- The first empty space can be filled in 3 possible ways.
- The second empty space can be filled in 2 possible ways, because you don't want to repeat yourself.

This gives you `3 × 2` possibilities in your case.

Let's go with another example. Say, you have five letters (`ABCDE`) and combo length of four `_ _ _ _`.

- We put any of five letters on the first empty space. This is five possibilities: A, B, C, D, E.
- Now for each possibility after the last step, no matter which letter we've chosen, now we have 4 letters left to choose from. If in the previous step we've chosen `A`, the corpus is now `BCDE` -- this is four possibilities. For `B`, we choose from `ACDE` -- this is again for possibilities. In total, since there were `5` ways to do previous step, and there are `4` ways to go after *any* of the previous choices, in total this is `20` possibilities: (AB, AC, AD, AE), (BA, BC, BD, BE), (CA, CB, CD, CE), (DA, DB, DC, DE), (EA, EB, EC, ED).
- Let's keep going. After picking two letters, we're left with `3`. With the same logic as before, for each of the previous 20 possibilities we have another 3 possibilities. This is `60` in total.
- And one more space left. We have two letters which we haven't chosen before. From any of the previous `60` possibilities, we now have two possibilities. That's `120` in total.

So we've arrived at this by multiplying `5 × 4 × 3 × 2`. Why start from `5`? Because we initially had 5 letters: `ABCDE`. Why have four numbers in our multiplication? Because there were 4 empty spaces: `_ _ _ _`.

In general, you keep multiplying a decremented value starting from `n`, and do this `k` times: `n × (n - 1) × ... × (n - k + 1)`.

The last value is `(n - k + 1)` because you are multiplying `k` values in total. From `n` to `(n - k + 1)` there are `k` values in total (inclusive).

We can test this with our `n = 5` and `k = 4` example. We said that the formula was `5 × 4 × 3 × 2`. Now look at the general formula: indeed, we start from `n = 5` and keep multiplying until we reach the number `5 - 4 + 1 = 2`.

---

In your function's signature, `n` is `setLength`, `k` is `comboLength`. The implementation should be trivial with the above formulas, so I'm leaving this to the reader.

---

These are called [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) with and without repetition.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer. The solution with repetition is done and clear (and very simple, just elevate n to power of k, now I feel silly for asking that!), but I don't understand at all this part: `In general, you keep multiplying with a lower value starting from n, and do this k times: n × (n - 1) × ... × (n - k + 1)` please could you add more details on that?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios Expanded. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand how to implement the logic in an algorithm. In your example, if instead 5 letters I have 8, and the same combo length/spaces of 4, the resulting return value and formula following your indications would be `8*4*3*2`?, but obviously it is not (so i'm missing something). I'm too old and bad for this!.

Comment: No, it would be `8 * 7 * 6 * 5`.

Comment: hmmm... I obtain the right value to calculate some combinations, and wrong value for some others. Maybe could you check this code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?. Sorry if im bothering you. The part on where you have put " (n - 1) × ... × (n - k + 1) " (the dots) I don't understand the meaning or how to "fill it". https://pastebin.com/DcqRchPu

Comment: You fill it with values between. Do a for-loop. For 10 letters with 8 places to put them, `10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3`. Please read the explanation, do not just jump into the formula.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally did it!. Thankyou again. Before marking your answer as accepted, please could you confirm me I didn't commit any mistake in my code? (or whether it could be simplified in some way): https://pastebin.com/a7nSS4tX

Comment: @ElektroStudios Looks good to me. I cannot speak for the language usage though, I do not work with C# or VB. But the algorithm looks fine.